# How do I sort the average of a group using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The data frame has country, height, and many other columns. I want to report the average height by country and sort it with the highest average on top. I am stuck at the sort. So far, I have this.

```
cH = df.("Country")["Height"].mean()
```

This allowed me to find the average height per country. However, now I need to sort this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    df= pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':['a','b','a','b'],
    'Height':[10,20,30,40]
})

df.groupby("Country", as_index=False).Height.mean().sort_values('Height', ascending=False)
```

**Output**

```
    Country Height
1   b       30
0   a       20
```